# laravel response json to xml conversion

Tags: php, xml, json, laravel

I am trying to have a `type=xml/json` on the response of my API.
I am using the laravel 4 framework and I was trying to look for such library.

I found `jmsyst.com/libs/serializer` but I cant make it work for laravel so I continued to look for another that can be easily added to laravel 4, So I finally found `github.com/SoapBox/laravel-formatter`.

I installed it into laravel with composer as `"hitsend/laravel-formatter": "dev-master"`
All went well and I went ahead to add the provider on the config/app.php

```
'SoapBox\Formatter\FormatterServiceProvider',
```

But laravel now returns the error:

```
Class 'SoapBox\Formatter\FormatterServiceProvider' not found
```

I tried to check my autoload_namespaces.php and saw that hitsend is there.
Why is it not detected the provider?

Comment: type=xml/json sounds wrong, it should propably be application/json or text/xml, but I don't know laravel actually.

Comment: type=xml or type=json on the query string like `api.site.com/api?type=xml` if i want the returned data to be formatted to xml.

Comment: Did you find any solution here?